# Project name must match iTunes Connect app name?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app is called Easy Calculator. In iTunes Connect, when I create my app profile, does the app name have to match my project name in Xcode? What if the name already exists somewhere else in the App Store?

Comment: when you say app name, are you referring to the name that is shown below the icon on the phone/springboard? or is it the name that is seen in the app store title? Either way, it doesn't matter if how you name your project or target. Also, I have seen many apps with the same names (on the phone) show up on the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The bundle IDs should match. They're generally something like `com.youcompany.awesomeapp`.

Answer (score 3):

Your app name in iTunes Connect doesn't need to match the name of your project in Xcode. I know this from experience - **I have an app named Physics! Pro whose project name in Xcode is 'PhysicsAppBuild2Primary'.** Of course, this is an extreme case, but it serves to illustrate.

The only thing that needs to match between iTunes and Xcode is your Bundle ID. Usually this follows a reverse-DNS style - `com.erwaysoftware.physicspro` would be my Bundle ID (sometimes called App ID). The App ID is actually different from the bundle ID - but that's another topic. I hope I have answered your question satisfactorily!